# Using ng-bootstrap components with Angular2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

What additional steps I have to do for using ng-bootstrap components except the steps presenting in http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/??. After doing that I have an error like this:

> Error: TypeError: require is not a function(…)    angular2-polyfills.js:332

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, I add the following script, it was needing it.

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
```